# How to uninstall Jdownloader 2 beta?

Tags: uninstall, jdownloader

I want to uninstall Jdownloader 2 beta, having taken the steps in this webpage: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/tag/13-04/.

Apparently, it is a sort of installation with ".sh" files. What I have figured out is that the regular "Jdownloader" can be removed writing commands such as:

```
 sudo apt-get purge jdownloader
```

and so forth. However, I have been trying the same way with "Jdownloader 2 beta"  but it does not work out.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

So ...

```
./Uninstall\ JDownloader
```

from the directory where you installed it and it will start this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. However the first window you posted says nothing to me cause you did not mention how to access to it. Secondly, i ran the command you said and the terminal message is:bash: ./Uninstall JDownloader: No such file or directory.
Something else you come up with?. Thanks

Comment: And you did not tell us where you installed it ;) As you can see in the image I issued the command from terminal from the directory it was installed (for me that was `~/jd2`) It would be the same place from where you start it so it should be clear where to find the uninstaller(?)

Comment: I got it.But i don't still know what to write. Please help me by writing at least the last response to this message. I found out in the "default Jdownloader 2 beta settings" the  downloaded files folder destination: /home/walter/downloads.  "/home" is the main disk,where all programs are apparently installed.  i got another one but it was the one which contained windows, and it is only used for storage purposes.walter is the user, my name. So,having said that. Would you mind to give me, if possible,the exact sequence of commands to enter in the terminal in order unistall window pops up.?thanks

Comment: Thanks... Itś always good to remember that if you installed JDownloader using "sudo", de default instaletion folder is /opt/jd2. Otherwise it will be instaled in the home folder.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple. Go to the directory, in `/usr/local/jd2/` and there is Unistall JDownloader.

Right-click and open terminal in this directory. Then just run

```
sudo ./Uninstall\ JDownloader
```

to start the uninstall. Then click next... next... next...  :-p

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the only person slightly interested in answering my question. Nevertheless, I must say I was unable to do it the way they said. I finally discovered the solution, though. It is simple and clear as water.

For people who might have the same problem in near/far future, this is the solution: When Ubuntu or whatever is installing "Jdownloader 2 beta", it automatically creates a folder in "home" destination. So:

1. Go there, find the `jd2` folder, and among the considerable number of files look for the one called `UnistallalJdownloader`, `Uninstall Jdownloader`, or similar (I deleted it already).
2. Click it and press right button, then choose the option "open with terminal" and it will eventually launch the uninstall window.
3. The rest is simple, follow the instructions and that is it. Thanks to me, [to Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/a/393186/22949).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the thread, because I had the same issue. I started with

```
$ sudo apt-get purge jdownloader
```

next - (navigated to home folder and cd into jd2)

```
$ ./Uninstall\ JDownloader
```

most of the bundle was gone but some lock and port files remained. I was a bit suspicious. I did the following next.

```
$ cd ..
```

so I was sitting in `/jd2`

```
$ rm -r -f jd2
```

everything in there gone. I still have some idea there might be a sneaky little config file opening ports in the night-time (: haha :) so perhaps a bit more testing is required. I will use etherape and ntop to check and get back.

Actually, while typing this the jdownloader popped up and notified there are updates. Question answered. [spyware]

Answer (score 0):

The installation directory is "/opt/jd2". To uninstall JDownloader, run the file "Uninstall Jdownloader" as the user "root". To become the root user, execute the command "sudo su". A window similar to the Windows Uninstaller will open. Click "Next" multiple times until the process is complete. Finally, use the command "rm -rf /opt/jd2" to delete the directory.

1. Day: 3 of Mar of 2024
2. OS: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04