# How to uninstall jdownloader completely?

Tags: software-installation

So I installed jdownloader directly from terminal , but I experienced a problem where it wasn't allowing me to set download directory to external drive.
I used the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader 
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install jdownloader-installer
```

I tried to uninstall it through terminal using `sudo apt-get purge jdownloader` but it showed `Unable to locate package jdownloader` so I tried to install directly from the jdownloader website without uninstalling the first install (as the jdownloader website download fixed my problem). This second install allowed me to do what I needed, but it required me to restart in order to use ffmpeg. After restarting when I started the second download it opened the first install.  I tried to uninstall through the uninstall command on jdownloader in an effort to remove both installs but, it removed only the second one.

The first install shows on snap, and in the home folder. I tried to delete the home folder one, but if I run the icon it installs again.

I followed this as well, but to no success. [How to uninstall Jdownloader 2 beta?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393181/how-to-uninstall-jdownloader-2-beta)

This is the icon that shows when I search Jdownlader on my PC . If I run it it opens Jdownloader2. If I remember correctly this icon showed after I installed Jdownloader from the official website and there was a first icon from the first/terminal install.

[image: Image icon]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jdownloader is packaged as a snap package called jdownloader2 in Ubuntu. Your jdownloader is installed as a snap package, so first uninstall whatever other versions of jdownloader are installed, and then use the `snap` terminal command to uninstall it as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove jdownloader-installer
cd /usr/local/jd2/
sudo ./Uninstall\ JDownloader
sudo snap remove jdownloader2
```